# Test Android PackageManager.getInstaller()

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Maybe I am missing something **very** obvious here:

I wanted to test the `PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()`. When I test my app through eclipse, or even as a standalone apk, the above method returns `null` as expected. But for users who install through **Google Play** or **Amazon AppStore**, the returned value will not be `null`.

My question is how do I test this before putting my app into production?
(**Eg.** Is something like this possible: upload a draft in Android Developer Console, and without moving it to production, somehow access it through Google Play, maybe by using a device which is setup with the same account as my Developer Console account; and then install and test it on my test device?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

If what you want is to be able to test an actual install from google play then use their Alpha  and Beta programs. [See here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) for a description of the program.

**Original Answer:**

If what you want is to just test your handling of this case, then you can use the BuildConfig.DEBUG flag to give you a dummy value when you are in DEBUG mode.

```
String installer;
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    installer = "com.android.vending";
} else {
    installer = pm.getInstallerPackageNamge(myPackage);
}
```

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for. I am wondering if there is a way that I can upload a draft to the Android Developer console, and test it by somehow installing from Google Play. I'll update the question to say that.

Comment: Ah, that is it! Now I remember this. Please make your update as the main answer, and I will accept it :).

Comment: Done. Left the other answer in case it helps somebody later and to make these comments make sense. :)